# How to fetch data from multiple API's at the same time - that require a different seaarch prase

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an app that fetches data from 2 different APIs at the same time based on the user's search.

The app is supposed to fetch current crypto prices and historical data. But the APIs use 2 different formats for the symbol, like so:

1.

- BTC-USD (yahoo.com/**BTC-USD**)
- BITCOIN (coingecko.com/api/**BITCOIN**)

if someone looks up 'BITCOIN' it's only going to pull up data from 1 API, because the other 1 requires 'BTC-USD'

2.

- ETH-USD (yahoo.com/**ETH-USD**)
- ETHEREUM coingecko.com/api/**ETHEREUM**

Is it possible to somehow fetch data from both APIs at the same time-based?

I guess I could see some solutions (hardcoding the data, or switching APIs so they use the same format), altho this path seems pretty work-intensive.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: you can create a `JSON` to store different crypto symbols for different APIs and use it to access the right symbol while calling those APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` if you want fetch data from 2 different API's at the sane time:

```
const fetchData = async (yahoo_API_URL, coingecko_API_URL) => {
    const fetchYahoo = fetch(yahoo_API_URL, /* config */)
    const fetchCoingecko = fetch(coingecko_API_URL, /* config */)
    const [fetchYahooRes, fetchCoingeckoRes] = await Promise.all([fetchYahoo, fetchCoingecko])
    const [cryptoPriceFromYahoo, cryptoPriceFromCoingecko] = await Promise.all([fetchYahooRes.json(), fetchCoingeckoRes.json()])
    ...
  }

  fetchData('yahoo.com/BTC-USD', 'coingecko.com/api/BITCOIN')
  fetchData('yahoo.com/ETH-USD', 'coingecko.com/api/ETHEREUM')
```

Comment: wow, i almost gave up on trying and was about to re do the whole application.. but you gave me hope  thanks